# Getting edge positions of cube?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently remaking the game [Stack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.stack&hl=en) but I've hit a kind of a roadblock.

What I'm trying to achieve is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSCbQ.jpg

So basically the cube that's placed on top has to be cut in 2 pieces and the overhanging bit has to fall off.

The problem is that I have absolutely no idea how I can achieve this or what I have to google, so I'm turning to you guys.

Any help or pointers is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the way you do that in games is: simply make two new cubes.

Your easiest approach:

Say you have a cube C which is 10 cm long.

Actually just **duplicate** it in the identical place, so you now have two identical cubes C and D.

Change C to be say 7 cm long.

Change D to be say 3 cm long.

If the old center-point of C was at say "100", you can see that the new center point of C would be at 103.5, and the new center-point of D would be a 98.5.

It's really that simple in concept.  This is the only way to do it: swap to two new models.

Note that Unity engineering is "not easy": you'll have to learn how to change the **scale** of cubes, and deal with other issues. Things you see in games which look simple often take **months** of work.

Comment: Sorry, busy days! I also posted the question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/4jfchs/getting_edges_of_cube_remaking_stack_help/) and along with someone's explanation and a video of stream of someone remaking Stack and I got it to work, they also used the same kind of logic you explained, thanks!

Comment: Hey @BramNouwen - thaht's good.  Would you mind please to TICK an answer here on this site (green "check mark" on your left). As a new user, it's important to close out questions so you get points, and thus avoid moderation.  Folks won't answer your future questions unless you tick, tick!  Cheers!